# Переменные в тексте Битрикс

Tags: битрикс

Всем привет!
Хочу сделать переменную для подмены в тексте Битрикс, вида #PHONE#, чтобы можно было бы вставить ее в текст и она автоматически подставляла нужные данные в тексте.

Как такое можно реализовать или куда копать? Неудалось найти информацию по данному вопросу. Спасибо

Comment: Опишите более подробно, для решения какой задачи вам нужна такая переменная.

Answer (score 0):

Если вопрос про шаблон, то используется метод Loc::getMessage
https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_d7/bitrix/main/localization/loc/getmessage.php

Comment: Нет. Чтобы можно было просто в тексте указать при редактировании

Answer (score 0):

Есть решение на JS

```js
        var city = $('.city_sel').text()
                                var word = '#CITY#'
                                var queue = [document.body]
                                var curr
                            ;
                            while (curr = queue.pop()) {
                                if (!curr.textContent.match(word)) continue;
                                for (var i = 0; i < curr.childNodes.length; ++i) {
                                    switch (curr.childNodes[i].nodeType) {
                                        case Node.TEXT_NODE : // 3
                                            if (curr.childNodes[i].textContent.match(word)) {
                                                console.log("Found!");
                                                console.log(curr);
                                                let text = curr.innerText.replace(word, city);
                                                curr.innerText = text
                                                // you might want to end your search here.
                                            }
                                            break;
                                        case Node.ELEMENT_NODE : // 1
                                            queue.push(curr.childNodes[i]);
                                            break;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
```